# Is there any way to do cross domain request to get pure json data without modifying server side?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

In a web page I want to download data from a certain URL.(Well just a google api).
Since I want to a cross domain access, I should use "jsonp".
But the url(google api) only return json which I cannot modify the format.
A "jsonp" request always throws an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " error.

Of course I can set up a backend server as proxy.
Is there any way to solve this problem only on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is public and Google has enabled CORS on their servers using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, then nothing more is required than a simple HTTP request using the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com/some.json');

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  console.log(data);
}

xhr.send(null);
```

If the example above fails that means the data isn't public and some kind of authentication is required - for example OAuth2, and it would be easier in this case to use their provided (*backend*) libraries for doing OAuth.

You can learn more about CORS here:

- http://enable-cors.org
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors